# How to create a database diagram for SQL Server in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-tools

I need to make a Visual Studio application that connects to a database in SQL Server, and I've seen a lot of people use the "create database diagram" for this, but the option doesn't appear in my Visual studio.

[image]

The option to create a diagram should be between the Database name ("Tienda") and Tables, but it isn't there.

Comment: Install "SQL Management Studio", Its Free.

Comment: I obviously have sql management studio, but I need to do this in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: nothing is obvious, you need to pretend we have no context into what problem you're trying to solve... because we don't.  ***Why*** do you need to do it in VS2015.  What problem are you trying to solve for, as there might be another way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was removed as of VS 2013

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5a4ezk9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has discontinued feature in visual studio 2015, you can do it in Microsoft SQL management studio 2014/2016